# How does EF Core 3 build the MigrationsHistory Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-3.0

I have got to a strange stalemate with ef, where it insists on implementing a bad migration that set Time to time (for a TimeSpan) in sql no matter what I do.

I have deleted the database and the migrations folder and redeployed countless times and followed every person's version of fixing unwanted migrations with no look.
If I do script-migrations with no Database and no migrations folder (so no context model snapshot etc.) the sql script wants to add this

```
ALTER TABLE [TimeCards] ADD [Time] time NOT NULL DEFAULT '00:00:00';
GO
INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'20200615144922_Time_Property', N'3.1.3');
```

So my question how the hell does it build the migrations table/script when there is no migrations folder.

Comment: "EF Core 6" isn't a thing. Do you mean EF6 - or EF Core 3?

Comment: Sorry Yes EF core 3

Answer (score 0):

When you deleted the Migrations folder, did you also delete the model snapshot file? (*MyDbContext*Snapshot.cs) Migrations are generated by comparing the current model to the model in this snapshot.